# I can not log in openerp after restart openerp-server

Tags: python, server, odoo, openerp-7

I have already succeed to install openerp7, but when I restart openerp-server, I can't login again. I get this error:

```
...

File "/opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp/tools/safe_eval.py", line 158, in test_expr
code_obj = compile(expr, "", mode)
  File "<string>", line 25
    'author': 'Odoo Indonesia,  
                             ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Before I restarted openerp-server, when I logged in, I got this error:

```
value error : invalid field....
```

And I got several similar errors. I'm thinking, how is possible that after restarting the server, suddenly I can't log in again.

Comment: Check all the modules with that author `Odoo Indonesia` and check if the string of the author in the file `__openerp__.py` is correct. You can remove them if you don't need them to avoid the error

Comment: do you have any custom module linked?

Comment: sorry for my late respon, i need to take a rest for my brain. i have custom module, before i restart openerp-server, i don't find this error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your custom module manifest file you have typo, find that module using command :

```
grep -nr "'author': 'Odoo Indonesia,"  --include=*.py
```

this will give you file with problem  and then replace line

```
'author': 'Odoo Indonesia,
```

with

```
'author': 'Odoo Indonesia',
```

This should fix above error.

Bests

Comment: btw, was it possible the script *.py changed automatically..?